# problem with relation hasmany laravel proprty retro

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have a relation hasMany but it doesn't work at my controller

code season model :

```
public function retro () {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Retrocession','season_id');
}
```

code controller :

```
$hotelagencie = HotelAgency::find($id) ;
    $hotel = $hotelagencie->hotel;
    $season = $hotel->seasons;
    return  $season->retro
```

Ereur : Property [retro] does not exist on this collection instance.

Thxyou .

Comment: seasons looks like collection. try `$hotel->seasons->first()->retro`

Comment: it work but this return just the first line and i have me i have many lines

Comment: You have to do a foreach loop to get multiple results

Comment: i try this `foreach ( $season as $ret) {

            return  $ret->retros;

        }`   but i still get just the first line i have two line in my database with but i still get just the frist one

Comment: @Nablialaa I think I understand your problem. `$hotel->seasons` is a collection( as it has many results), yet you are sticking it into a variable called `$season`. This makes it confusing as it is not 1 season but the whole collection of seasons. A season has a function/relationship `retro()`. A collection does not. Thats why `$hotel->seasons->first()->retro` is working. You are selecting the first of all seasons. The real question after this observation is: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to return all retrocessions your selection found?

Comment: Yess this is what i want .. i want to get all the retrocessions for seasons .. the hotel has many seasons and each seasons has retocessions so i want to return each retrocessions for this hotel seasons .. howa can i get this work thankyou @Rob Biermann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We confirmed what you want(Select all the retro from all the seasons), so I think I can give you an answer:

This is what you got:

```
$hotelagencie = HotelAgency::find($id) ;
    $hotel = $hotelagencie->hotel;
    $season = $hotel->seasons;
    return  $season->retro
```

This is what I think it needs to be:

```
$hotelagencie = HotelAgency::find($id) ;
    $hotel = $hotelagencie->hotel;
    $seasons = $hotel->seasons;
    return $seasons->pluck('retro');
```

For more info on what `pluck()` is and how to use it, please refer to the official docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck

I hope it helps ;)